# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: django_content_type.name?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I added a new model in models.py as:

```
class Attendence_Mgmt(models.Model):    
    teacher_name=models.ForeignKey(Teacher_Mgmt)
    date=models.DateField(blank=False)
    intime=models.TimeField(blank=False)
    outtime=models.TimeField(blank=False)
```

When i was working on my project and i run make-migrations command, it runs fine but when i run the migrate command, i suddenly encountered the above kind of error.

Why is the the above type of error occurred?
How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the stack trace for the error? The code you've provided has nothing to do (directly) with the error

Answer (score 3):

I have got the same problem, when trying to rollback migrations on Django 2.1.5. The migrations were generated using Django 2.0+.

I have managed to solve it by running:

```
$ manage.py migrate contenttypes 0001_initial
$ manage.py migrate <my_app> zero
$ manage.py migrate contenttypes
$ manage.py migrate auth
```

I came to this solution by listing migrations with `manage.py showmigrations`:

```
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
```

Since, the error message was `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: django_content_type.name` and the second `contenttypes` migration explicitely removes `name`, I have tried to temporarily revert this migration and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for this, I was starting to go crazy. Your answer made me realize what the problem probably is. The way Django calculates the order of migrations is kinda fucked up, I've had problems with it before. Somehow the migration I was trying to reverse was causing Django to "go back in time" and run database commands thinking content type names still exist. Since I have data in my tables, I couldn't migrate back to zero so instead I simply added `('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name')` in the dependencies of the migration I wanted to revert. Worked like a charm 

Comment: @Arial, adding the dependency really did the trick! Been searching for a solution for hours. And I can verify that my Django version has been 2.0 from the get-go. This really seems like a bug in Django. Wasn't able to figure out what goes wrong. Inner workings of Django migrations are a bit too hairy.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is with changing the django version. If you are upgrade your django to 1.8 but it's developed on 1.7 .... this is the problem. I'm not sure but try this: python manage.py migrate contenttypes

Comment: To solve this problem, i actually first delete my sqllite database and after that, i deleted my entire migrations. Then running makemigration and then migration command, it is running fine now.